# How many 5 digit numbers with the below conditions

Tags: combinatorics

A friend who is in school asked for help and I must admit my maths is rusty and I'm not even sure how to approach this:

How many 5 digit numbers are there that meet the criteria:

1. Divisible by 4
2. When divided by 5 leftover is 2 (I guess this means it has to end with 2)
3. The thousands (2nd digit) are odd
4. The sum of 10 thousand and hundred digits (1st and 3rd digit is 8)

I get to 200, but the book says the result is 175 (with no explanation)

Here is my calculation

10k digit: 8options (1-8)
1k digit: 5 options (1,3,5,7,9)
100 digit: 1 option (8-10k digit)
10 digit: 5 options (1,3,5,7,9, otherwise it's not divisible by 4)
1 digit: 1 option (2 because of the divided by 5 thing)
Thanks.

Comment: Hint:  the first two conditions tell you a lot about the least two digits of your number.  The fourth condition tells you the third digit, so that only leaves two digits you can vary.  Note that you'll need to specify whether or not the lead digit can be $0$ (usually that's what people mean when they specify a number of digits, but it's good to confirm).

Comment: Thanks s lot, I updated the question after the friend came back with a more comprehensive instructions

Comment: Please edit to include your calculation.  Note that, post edit, most of hint is still valid, though now the third digit is not specified uniquely.

Comment: Thanks, edited to add the calculation

Comment: Looks good.  I also get $200$, following essentially the same calculation you do.  Apparently they are excluding one case for the first digit, though I can't see any basis for doing that (maybe they don't want any of the digits to be $0$?  But that isn't specified in what you wrote).

Comment: Yeah I thought the same but the question does not specify that so who knows. Thanks a lot for your help

Comment: I suspect the authors without really consciously thinking about about it, assumed if we have $Te + H = 8$ then by symmetry $H + Te= 8$ and as $Te$ can not be equal to $0$ And $H$ can not equal $8$ then $H$ can not be equal to $0$ and $Te$ can not be equal to $8$ either.  .... But if you *do* think about this it becomes clear that that is obviously *not* valid.  $H$ is obviously allowed to be $0$ (but not $8$) and $Te$ is allowed to be $8$ (but not $0$) and there is no "symmetry".